# LEGO set names in non-English language?

Tags: set-database

English names can be found easily for nearly all LEGO sets on [BrickLink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=&catType=S&catID=&itemYear=) and other sites.
However, the sets have names in other languages as well.

Is there an overview of set names in languages other than English? I look for a German translation.

To clarify this question a bit, I rather look for some kind of lists or databases including older sets from the 80's and 90's.
So hitting the catalogs is the way I'm currently doing but this way is not very efficiant, but hey: it's a bit beeing a boy in the good old LEGO times...  ;-D

So: "No" might be a valid answer as well!

Comment: You might want to contact the admins of brickset and bricklink and suggest that they add this feature.

Comment: If you provide exact set number some of us may have German language catalogs and check out the name for you.

Comment: @Alex, thank you, but I do not want to misuse Bricks.SE (and there users) to do my "routine work". ;-) A lot of the German catalogs can be found online and a few of my LEGO "heyday" in the 90's I still own. I just wondered if an IT guy could use IT to automate things... :-D  Indeed, looking in catalogs is what I'm currently doing.

Comment: For last several years TLG have been releasing catalogs in PDF format as well. You could give a try to OCR them and perhaps get some data to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lego instructions are available [auf Deutsch](https://www.lego.com/de-de/service/buildinginstructions) but you might have to type the set numbers in one at a time in order to see the set names displayed.

For older sets German Catalogs might be available on [Brickset](https://brickset.com/library/catalogues?query=Medium%20European%25) to find out the names the "manual" way.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this only contains rather newer sets (I'm looking for my "old" ones from the 90's. Furthermore, I was more looking for some kind of database so I could automate this part a bit.

Comment: As far as I know, the historical entries on (say) BrickLink have come from volunteers retyping what they found in old catalogs; until someone puts in the time to do the same for old German catalogs, it likely won't exist. So unless you can convince a group of people to join you in this quest, I fear it's Do It Yourself.

Comment: I completed your answer with the "catalog" part from the comments to have a more complete answer.